# docker-machine create error ... VBoxManage: error: Unknown option: --synthcpu

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I am trying to create docker-machine using virtualbox as the driver.

```
➜  ~  docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

However, I am getting following error

```
INFO[0000] Creating SSH key...
INFO[0000] Creating VirtualBox VM...
ERRO[0005] Error creating machine: exit status 1
WARN[0005] You will want to check the provider to make sure the machine and associated resources were properly removed.
FATA[0005] Error creating machine
```

I ran it with --debug option and here is the detailed [log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hshira/c3fc56aa8abeb1e9bc91/raw/13ceecad5f71dec5885bedba1245f0334c7e24dd/docker-machine-create-vbox)

I see the following error at the end of the log --

```
VBoxManage: error: Unknown option: --synthcpu
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled docker toolbox and reinstalled it using this shell script -- https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/osx/uninstall.sh

Fixed the problem.